# HBase - MultiGet and Selective Columns

Tags: rest, hbase

I can query using `multiget` to be able to selectively query multiple random rows from HBase.

`http://hostname:port/tablename/multiget/?row=row1&row=row2`

For selecting few columns,

`http://hostname:port/tablename/rowkey/columnFamily:columnName`

How to be able to use `multiget` and be able to select only few columns at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3541) (HBASE-3541) JIRA issue for multi-gets, it seems like there is no option to specify columns when using multiget. However, it also seems like it would be pretty simple to add this functionality.

EDIT: the issue I opened regarding this problem (linked [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-15870)) was resolved and included in HBase's 1.3.0 release, and now it is possible to select only specific columns.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Currently, it is simply not possible to "select only  few columns" as Joel asked. However, looking at the code enabling multi-gets as seen in linked JIRA issue, adding this functionality may be pretty simple